# How to catch error thrown in the builder function of showDialog, in the caller function?

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, flutter-future, flutter-dialog

I made a function to show a loading dialog while a `Future` is doing its computation, and automatically dismiss the dialog when the `Future` completes. To achieve this, I put a try-catch block inside a `Future` in the builder function like this:

```dart
Future<T?> showLoadingDialog<T>({
  required BuildContext context,
  required Future<T> future,
}) {
  return showDialog<T>(
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      Future(() async {
        try {
          final value = await future;
          if (context.mounted) {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(value);
          }
        } catch (_) {
          Navigator.of(context).pop();
          rethrow;
        }
      });

      return Dialog(
        // ...
      );
    },
    // ...
  );
}
```

I want the caller function (for example, a function inside a `StatefulWidget` that is trying to get the result value from the dialog) to be able to catch error thrown by the `Future`. This is an example of where the function is called:

```dart
class LoginForm extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const LoginForm({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<ConsumerStatefulWidget> createState() => _LoginFormState();
}

class _LoginFormState extends ConsumerState<LoginForm> {
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  @override
  void dispose() {
    emailController.dispose();
    passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  Future<void> login() async {
    final httpClient = ref.read(httpClientProvider);

    try {
      final response = await showLoadingDialog(
        context: context,
        future: httpClient.post('/login', data: {
          'email': emailController.text,
          'password': passwordController.text,
        }),
      );

      // should not reach here
    } on DioException catch (e) {
      // should catch here
    }
  }

  // ...
}
```

Even though I put `rethrow` in the catch block inside the `showDialog`'s builder function, the caller function can't catch the error. What happened is the function still continue to execute lines after the `showLoadingDialog` call in the try block and the error is not caught.

Comment: I believe you can return a Future.error and the caller upon awaiting the value will throw, and that should be able to be caught